# Difference between optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] and scheduler.get_lr()[0]

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

```
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
from torchvision.models import AlexNet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
 
model = AlexNet(num_classes=2)
optimizer = optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(), lr=0.05)
 

 
scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, gamma=0.1)
plt.figure()
x = list(range(100))
y = []
for epoch in range(100):
    scheduler.step()
    lr = scheduler.get_lr()
    y.append(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])
    #y.append(scheduler.get_lr()[0])
 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig("a.jpg")
```

if i use:

```
y.append(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])
```

the result is right:
[image]

if i use:

```
y.append(scheduler.get_lr()[0])
```

the result seems wrong:
[image]

why optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] and scheduler.get_lr()[0] are different?
And what's the true learing-rate of my network?

My pytorch version is   1.9.1

I check StepLR's source code:

```
class StepLR(_LRScheduler):
    """Decays the learning rate of each parameter group by gamma every
    step_size epochs. Notice that such decay can happen simultaneously with
    other changes to the learning rate from outside this scheduler. When
    last_epoch=-1, sets initial lr as lr.

    Args:
        optimizer (Optimizer): Wrapped optimizer.
        step_size (int): Period of learning rate decay.
        gamma (float): Multiplicative factor of learning rate decay.
            Default: 0.1.
        last_epoch (int): The index of last epoch. Default: -1.
        verbose (bool): If ``True``, prints a message to stdout for
            each update. Default: ``False``.

    Example:
        >>> # Assuming optimizer uses lr = 0.05 for all groups
        >>> # lr = 0.05     if epoch < 30
        >>> # lr = 0.005    if 30 <= epoch < 60
        >>> # lr = 0.0005   if 60 <= epoch < 90
        >>> # ...
        >>> scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, gamma=0.1)
        >>> for epoch in range(100):
        >>>     train(...)
        >>>     validate(...)
        >>>     scheduler.step()
    """

    def __init__(self, optimizer, step_size, gamma=0.1, last_epoch=-1, verbose=False):
        self.step_size = step_size
        self.gamma = gamma
        super(StepLR, self).__init__(optimizer, last_epoch, verbose)

    def get_lr(self):
        if not self._get_lr_called_within_step:
            warnings.warn("To get the last learning rate computed by the scheduler, "
                          "please use `get_last_lr()`.", UserWarning)

        if (self.last_epoch == 0) or (self.last_epoch % self.step_size != 0):
            return [group['lr'] for group in self.optimizer.param_groups]
        return [group['lr'] * self.gamma
                for group in self.optimizer.param_groups]

    def _get_closed_form_lr(self):
        return [base_lr * self.gamma ** (self.last_epoch // self.step_size)
                for base_lr in self.base_lrs]
```

why it ruturns  group['lr'] * self.gamma? It seems that optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] and scheduler.get_lr()[0] are the same in previous version

Comment: it's reported as a bug before:https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22107 and then fixed. But now it appears again. Even optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR has the same problem